# Is there a way to "subclass" a modifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui, modifier

I am developing an app using SwiftUI. My first one.

This app uses `.sheet()`, `.actionSheet()` and `.alert()` but these modifiers have very generic names.

Suppose I use `.sheet()` to show forms, `.actionSheet()` to show menus and `.alert()` to show error messages. I have to constantly remember what functions each one do.

It would be nice to convert them from `.sheet()`, `.actionSheet()` and `.alert()` to `.showForm()`, `.showMenu()` and `.showMessages()`

is it possible to "subclass" `.sheet()`, `.actionSheet()` and `.alert()`, giving them custom names?

Comment: Do you want the same functionality but with a new name?

Comment: yes, so it is easier to understand what each one is reponsible for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of possible approach with custom extension that wraps needed view.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
extension View {
    func showForm<Content: View>(isActive: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        self.sheet(isPresented: isActive, content: {
            Form { content() }
        })
    }
}

struct DemoShowForm: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Demo") { self.isActive = true }
            .showForm(isActive: $isActive) {
                Button("Close") { self.isActive = false }
            }
    }
}
```